# python copy file based on header

Tags: python

On Python, I need help in searching for files with a specific header type(PST file, header sequence 21 42 44 4E) and then copy them to my saved files directory.

below are the relevant excerpts from my code.

```
# get working directory of my program
ori_path=os.getcwd()
# this is where the file is saved(from the root directory of my program)
temp = "\etc\Saved Files"
# obtain value written in textbox, the path to search
path_to_copy_from=self.textbox.GetValue()
# create the absolute destination path so that the files don't end up somewhere they shouldn't be  
copy_path="{}{}".format(ori_path,temp)     
# change working directory to the one specified by user
os.chdir(path_to_copy_from)
```

I will be using shutil to do the copying like such:

```
shutil.copy(files,copy_path)
```

some searches I found mentioned using itertools, but I can't understand the example (hence, why I am asking the question). I need help in coming up with the code that will look at the file header and then invoke shutil if the header matches the PST header format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the first 4 bytes of a file in the hex format from your question:

```
header = ""
with open(path_to_copy_from, 'rb') as f:
    for i in range(4):
        byte = f.read(1)
        header += hex(ord(byte))[2:] + " "
```

You can then check for each file in the folder whether this `header` string matches the one you're looking for.

Comment: thanks @Junuxx. your code specifically targets a file, but the path i supplied was for a directory. however, by using glob i could run this code on the files in the directory. much love

Answer (score 0):

with junuxx's solution, i worked out a way to do this for all files in a directory. the final code looks like this

```
     import wx #this is for GUI interfaces i made to interact with the user. aka wxPython
     import os
     import glob
     import shutil
     #the above are the needed libraries. 
     path_to_copy_from=self.textbox.GetValue() #obtain value written in textbox(made with wxPython)
     if os.path.exists(path_to_copy_from):
        ori_path=os.getcwd()#get working directory of my program
        #combine ori_path and temp to create the destination path for files to be copied to
        copy_path="{}{}".format(ori_path,temp)
        #change working directory to the one specified by user
        os.chdir(path_to_copy_from)
            #to copy files based on header
            header = ""
            pst_header="21 42 44 4e "
            for self.files in glob.glob("*.*"):
                try:
                    with open(self.files, 'rb') as f:
                        for i in range(4):
                            byte = f.read(1)
                            header += hex(ord(byte))[2:] + " "

                        if header == pst_header:
                            shutil.copy(self.files,copy_path)
                            #the following 2 lines tells the user using a textbox i made earlier that something is happening. made for a textctrl i made with wxPython
                            self.textbox2.AppendText("Found file with .pst header.\n")
                            self.textbox2.AppendText("Copied {} to {}. \n".format(self.files,copy_path))
                            #to change copied file to read only
                            path_to_file="{}\{}".format(copy_path,self.files)
                            #set the file as read-only(for my program only, not necessary to have)
                            os.chmod(path_to_file,0444)
                        #to remove the string already in header for next iteration
                        header = "" 
                #simple exception handling. change as you need
                except TypeError, ex:
                    pass
                except IOError, ex:
                    pass
```

thanks very much :)